# Run Windows.Forms.webbrowser.Navigate in an async method?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I am writing a test program that opens a Webpage (exp. http://www.microsoft.com) on web browser of a windows.form by running the Navigate(URL) method in an async task function...

But it doesn't open the form and show the web page, although I have set breakpoints there and seen that the function before Navigate has been called, but not the Navigate function...

Code of Form:

```
public partial class ImmoScoutForm : Form
{
    public ImmoScoutForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.immoScoutWebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com");
        //NavigateWebPage();

        this.immoScoutWebBrowser.Navigated += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(webBrowser_Navigated);
        this.immoScoutWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowserDocumentCompleted);
    }

    public void NavigateWebPage()
    {
        this.immoScoutWebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com");
    }

    public void NavigateWebPage(WebBrowser wb)
    {
        if (wb != null)
        {
            wb.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com");
        }
    }

    private void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        HideScriptErrors(this.immoScoutWebBrowser, true);
        //if (ConnectBtn.IsEnabled)
        //{
        //    ConnectBtn.IsEnabled = false;
        //}
    }

    public void WebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Operation has completed !");
    }

    public static void HideScriptErrors(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb, bool Hide)
    {
        FieldInfo fiComWebBrowser = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).GetField("_axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (fiComWebBrowser == null) return;
        object objComWebBrowser = fiComWebBrowser.GetValue(wb);
        if (objComWebBrowser == null) return;
        objComWebBrowser.GetType().InvokeMember("Silent", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, objComWebBrowser, new object[] { Hide });
    }

}
```

class program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    private static ImmoScoutTestForms.ImmoScoutForm _immoScoutWebForm;

    public static ImmoScoutTestForms.ImmoScoutForm ImmoScoutWebForm
    {
        get { return _immoScoutWebForm; }
        set
        {
            _immoScoutWebForm = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        ImmoScoutWebForm = new ImmoScoutTestForms.ImmoScoutForm();
        //OpenThePage();

        Task.Run(() => CallPageAsyn().Wait());

        //Application.Run(ImmoScoutWebForm);

    }

    public static void OpenThePage()
    {
        if(ImmoScoutWebForm != null)
        {
            ImmoScoutWebForm.immoScoutWebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com");
        }

        Application.Run(ImmoScoutWebForm);
    }

    public static async Task CallPageAsyn()
    {
        await TestAsyn();
        ImmoScoutWebForm.immoScoutWebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com");
    }


    public static async Task TestAsyn()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting: ");
    }
```

}

I dont know why could the function after "await TestAsyn();" not be called and compiler has finished it? Or do you have any ideas how could i do it?